# ffmpeg: How to concat audio files and add background music in a single command?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Need to concat audio files and add background music in a single command.

Right now I use the following commands to do so,

**To concat:**

`ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i 5.mp4 -i 6.mp4 -i 7.mp4 -i 8.mp4 -i 9.mp4 -i 10.mp4  -filter_complex '[0:0][1:0]concat=n=10:v=0:a=1[out]'  -map '[out]' -strict -2 -y 10_final.mp4`

**To add background music:**

`ffmpeg -i 10_final.mp4 -i music.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1dB[a0];[1:a]volume=0.5[a1];[a0][a1]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" -ac 1 -ab 32000 -ar 22050 -strict -2 -y 10_with_music.mp4`

But his process is a quite time-consuming process as every time the file read/write happening to the output.

Is there a way I can merge these two above commands to a single so that the command should be optimized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i 5.mp4
       -i 6.mp4 -i 7.mp4 -i 8.mp4 -i 9.mp4 -i 10.mp4
       -i music.mp4
       -filter_complex '[0:0][1:0]...[9:0]concat=n=10:v=0:a=1,volume=1dB[a0];
                        [10]volume=0.5dB[a1];[a0][a1]amerge[a]'
       -map '[a]' -strict -2 -y 10_with_music.mp4
```

Comment: Also is there a way I can concat and convert in the same command? something like "all the input files are in ogg format and output in mp4".