# FFMPEG concatinate audio file and add background music

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, background, concatenation

I want to concatenate 2 audio files and play the third audio in the background. I used below code

ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i background.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1,volume=1dB[a0];[2]volume=0.5dB[a1];[a0][a1]amerge[a]" -map "[a]" -strict -2 -y final.mp3

suggested here [ffmpeg: How to concat audio files and add background music in a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013454/ffmpeg-how-to-concat-audio-files-and-add-background-music-in-a-single-command)

But it is giving error "The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_3 Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output."

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force the sample formats for inputs and output

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i background.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1,volume=1dB,aformat=fltp,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[a0];[2]volume=0.5dB,aformat=fltp,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[a1];[a0][a1]amerge,aformat=fltp[a]" -map "[a]" -strict -2 -y final.mp3
```

Comment: I tried but it is still not working.
Error: "The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_5 Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output. " You can check it on http://projects.udaantechnologies.com/mix-new/test.php

Comment: This is the root error: `No channel layout for input 1`. See edited command.

Comment: This is not working with FFMPEG version 1.2.1 error "Missing Key or no key/value separator found after key 'fltp' " and "Error initializing filter 'aformat' with args 'fltp'". Can you please suggest.

Comment: That is a very old version of ffmpeg. Upgrade.

Comment: Can not upgrade the version it is on shared hosting. Is there a way to make this script run on this version. Or some alternate script.

Comment: Thank you. I have switched my server now have updated version of FFmpeg and its working. Can you tell me how I can add the delay in this script? So every audio other than the background one start after 20-25 second the previous audio stops.

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i background.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:0]adelay=20000|20000[1a];[0:0][1a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1,volume=1dB,aformat=fltp,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[a0];[2]volume=0.5dB,aformat=fltp,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[a1];[a0][a1]amerge,aformat=fltp[a]" -map "[a]" -strict -2 -y final.mp3` - add an adelay filter for each audio after the first.